# Выделять область 3d модели при клике на кнопки js

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d, three.js

Нужно сделать, чтобы при клике на различные копки выделялись конкретные области. Например, если мы рассмотрим человека, то при нажатии кнопки с надписью "голова", голова человека 3d модели должна подсветится. Я так понимаю с этим может работать библиотека three.js, но я по ней подобного не нашел, если есть другие библиотеки способные это сделать я готов о них узнать. Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: хорошо, а если сделал, то как дальше работать, просто я не нашел ничего подобного, по типу как обращаться к конкретной области

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: Подскажите какие форматы 3d использовать при работе с этой библиотекой?

Comment: glTF - рекомендованный формат. Но можно и FBX, и OBJ. Поддерживаемых форматов - масса: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=loader . Лишь бы модель уже была как-то разбита по частям и их можно было бы идентифицировать в коде.